# Running Concurrent JetBrains Profiling Sessions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, dottrace

In the [dotTrace SDK API](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/#section=dottracesdk), is it possible to run more than one type of profiling at the same time? For example, I would like to run both **memory** and **timeline** profiling at the same time instead of twice individually, mainly because I would have to repeat my integration tests again when running the second profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run one kind of profiling session at a time. However, Timeline profiling will also track memory allocations. When viewing the results, the "Analysis Subject" filter is set to Time by default. The Call Stack and Call Tree views will show the top methods, with time shown as milliseconds and a percentage.

If you select "Memory Allocations" as the "Analysis Subject" filter, dotTrace will show you what's allocating memory, when, and how much. The thread view will filter down to when allocations were made, and the call stack/tree views will now show memory allocations, both as a percentage of overall allocations, and the actual MB value.

There is a [tutorial on JetBrains' web site](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Improving+App+Performance+with+Timeline+Profiling.+Memory+Traffic).

Comment: Cool I didn't know that was there! Thanks citizenmatt!